# how to get integer from select input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am a new to `AngularJS` and I try to get integer from select options. So, I have

```
<select class="form-control" id="decimation" placeholder="1 or 8" ng-model="data.settings.decimation">
                     <option type="number" value="1" ng-click="deci_bool=0">1</option>
                     <option type="number" value="8" ng-click="deci_bool=1">8</option>
</select>
```

and I want to bind the following input with the options values

```
<input ng-if="!deci_bool" type="number"  class="form-control" id="b_mesu" placeholder="Between 0 and {{data.settings.decimation + 96 }}" ng-model="data.settings.b_mesu" min="0" max="97" step="1" ng-click="b_mesu_ctrl" required>
```

But it seems `data.settings.decimation + 96` is concatenated as a string.

I tried, following `SO` post adding this in the `select` tag

```
ng-options="values.indexOf(data.settings.decimation) for data.settings.decimation in values"
```

but I get this error message

```
Error: [ngOptions:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_'
```

Someone can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:`placeholder="Between 0 and {{ (data.settings.decimation * 1)+78}}"`
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjoLx9te/)

P.S. Way strange, but `placeholder="Between 0 and {{ +data.settings.decimation +78}}"` don't working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
            <select class="form-control" id="decimation" placeholder="1 or 8" ng-model="decimation">
                     <option type="number" value="1" ng-click="deci_bool=0">1</option>
                     <option type="number" value="8" ng-click="deci_bool=1">8</option>
</select>

{{decimation}}<br/>

<input type="number" ng-model="b_mesu" ng-change="updateSelect()" min="0" max="97" step="1" ng-click="b_mesu_ctrl" required>

        </div>
```

JS :

```
$scope.updateSelect = function(){
        $scope.decimation = ($scope.decimation ? parseInt($scope.decimation) : 0 )+ parseInt($scope.b_mesu);
    }
```